# pdf page size with `standalone` + `tikz`

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, business-cards

I made up a simple business card with a standard size. However, when I open the pdf, it's 1.5mm larger (height and width).
I've tried to change `geometry` settings but to no avail.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperwidth=80mm,paperheight=50mm,pass,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric,shadows,shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}

\tikzstyle{linha} = [line width=7pt,MaterialGrey300]
\tikzstyle{linhafina} = [line width=3pt,MaterialGrey300]
\tikzstyle{bola} = [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt]
% yes, I know \tikzstyle is oudated, it's just easier to type.

\colorlet{cinza}{MaterialGrey300}


\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.append style={text=MaterialGrey800, 
%   font=\Huge
},
\node[opacity=.6,overlay,inner sep=0pt] (figura) 
%at (current page.center) 
{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}};  
\draw[line width=4pt,MaterialRed900%,fill=MaterialGrey300
%rounded corners=12pt
] (figura.south west) rectangle (figura.north east);
\node[yshift=1.5cm] (texto) at (figura.center)
 {\itshape \LARGE John Doe};
\node[below= 3pt of texto,overlay] (prof) {\scshape \large o\,r\,i\,o\,n};
\node[xshift=6pt,yshift=6pt,
align=left,anchor=south west,fill=white,opacity=.5,
text opacity=1,
rectangle,draw,rounded corners=2pt] (address) at (figura.south west) {\small Contact:\\e-mail: --- \\ website};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It's all good, but when I open the pdf in Acrobat Reader, the size is slightly larger (1.5mm):

[image]

Comment: your code doesn't compile, a closing bracket is missing. Add `\path[use as bounding box](figura.south west) rectangle (figura.north east);` before drawing the red line - it is in parts outside the picture.

Answer (score 1):

First how you compiled this file? It has essential errors. You have forget to close `[` front of `tikzpicture` environment. And you haven't specified where this node `\node[opacity=.6,overlay,inner sep=0pt] (figura)`  should be? You haven't specified that you are using `Laulatex`!! The final output size is `29.8 mm * 19.8 mm` or `1.17*0.78 in`.

[image]

Comment: CFG, thanks. Yes, a `[` got lost in copy-pasting. I thought it wasn't necessary to specify where the node should be because its a standalone figure, and as fontspec only works in Lua- or XeTeX, I forgot to comment that. But I guess clipping the figure does the job.

Comment: If you don't specify the location of a node, it ends up at `(0,0)`.